# Make top-border cover border completely

Tags: css

I have a nav bar with three links in it. If you look closely, you'll see that the dark green top-border on the hover and active anchors do not cover the brown border. Is there any way to make it do this?

Here's what it looks like;

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #C8E6C9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
}

header, ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

h1, li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  border-top: 6px solid #4CAF50
}


/*link actions*/

li a.active {
  background-color: #795548;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: 6px solid #388E3C;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #FDD835;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: 6px solid #388E3C;
  color: #795548;
}

li a.active:hover {
  background-color: #FDD835;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: 6px solid #388E3C;
}

a:first-child {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:first-child:hover {
  color: #795548;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <noscript>Please Use JavaScript you loser.</noscript>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <h1><a href="index.html">My Website</a></h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="page3.html">Getting Started</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way borders meet.  I'd suggest using a box-shadow instead of the top border

**NOTE:**

*You were clearing the floats with `overflow:hidden` on the `ul`. This would stop this technique working. I'd suggest an alternative clearfix method.*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #C8E6C9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
}
header,
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
h1,
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 0px 0px #4CAF50;
}
/*link actions*/

li a.active {
  background-color: #795548;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 0px #388E3C;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #FDD835;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 0 0px #388E3C;
  color: #795548;
}
li a.active:hover {
  background-color: #FDD835;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 0px 0px #388E3C;
}
a:first-child {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:first-child:hover {
  color: #795548;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <h1><a href="index.html">My Website</a></h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Getting Started</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh beautiful! I've marked this as the solution. 

I've just started and never used a box-shadow before, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Paulie_D commented, the brown in the top border of your anchor tag is the point of intersection between your top green and surrounding brown border. Because the background color of your li is already brown, I'd recommend removing the brown border like so:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #C8E6C9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
}

header, ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

h1, li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 6px solid #4CAF50
}

 h1 {
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}


/*link actions*/

li a.active {
  background-color: #795548;
  border-top: 6px solid #388E3C;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #FDD835;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: 6px solid #388E3C;
  color: #795548;
}

li a.active:hover {
  background-color: #FDD835;
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  border-top: 6px solid #388E3C;
}

a:first-child {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:first-child:hover {
  color: #795548;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <noscript>Please Use JavaScript you loser.</noscript>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <h1><a href="index.html">My Website</a></h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="page3.html">Getting Started</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: I also removed the fallback green border of your li to only apply to the h1.

Comment: The active link looks much better this way, however hovering over the links cause them to nudge the other links over. Also the problem still persists as I have a brown border on hover.